# Deriving a contingency truth table from two columns with yes and no values in R

Tags: r, truthtable

I've been trying to manipulate my data in R to something similar here [How to Find False Positive Prediction Count using R Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23009335/how-to-find-false-positive-prediction-count-using-r-script?rq=1) , but difficult doing it owing to lack of minimal example. My dataframe (called info) is like this:

**obs sim**  no no  no no  no no  no yes  yes yes  yes yes  yes no  no no  no no  no no  no no  yes yes  NA yes  no yes  yes yes  yes yes  yes yes

What I would like to obtain is a truth table that drops any row with NA in either column, with the result as follows:

```
   obs  sim 
     yes no  
yes    6 2  
 no    1 7
```

Comment: Not able to differentiate the `obs` column.  can you please format the code

Comment: could you link me to a table editor?, I have been searching for one here

Comment: May be you need `table(info[complete.cases(info),])`

Comment: `table` automatically drops `NA` values anyway. So `table(dat$sim, dat$obs)` should just do this out of the box I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `complete.cases` to create a logical index that will give `FALSE` if there is any NA in a row to subset the rows and then apply `table`

```
table(info[complete.cases(info),])
#    sim
#obs    no yes
#  no    7   2
#   yes  1   6
```

Or with `na.omit`

```
table(na.omit(info))
```

#### data

```
info <- structure(list(obs = c("no", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "yes", 
 "yes", "no", "no", "no", "no", "yes", NA, "no", "yes", "yes", 
 "yes"), sim = c("no", "no", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", 
 "no", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes"
 )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -17L))
```

Comment: Just `table(info)` gives the same result because of the `useNA` argument I think.

Comment: One would need to specifically make an effort in order to get the NA to be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

This will show you how to reassemble that ambiguous data presentation into one possible version of your truth.

```
dat <- scan(text=" no no no no no no no yes yes yes yes yes yes no no no no no no no no no yes yes NA yes no yes yes yes yes yes yes yes", what="")
Read 34 items
mdat <- matrix( dat, ncol=2, dimnames=list(NULL, c("obs","sim")))

 mdat
#------------
      obs   sim  
 [1,] "no"  "no" 
 [2,] "no"  "no" 
 [3,] "no"  "no" 
 [4,] "no"  "no" 
 [5,] "no"  "no" 
 [6,] "no"  "yes"
 [7,] "no"  "yes"
 [8,] "yes" NA   
 [9,] "yes" "yes"
[10,] "yes" "no" 
[11,] "yes" "yes"
[12,] "yes" "yes"
[13,] "yes" "yes"
[14,] "no"  "yes"
[15,] "no"  "yes"
[16,] "no"  "yes"
[17,] "no"  "yes"

 ?table
 table(mdat[,1],mdat[,2], dnn =list("obs","sim"))
#--------------
     sim
obs   no yes
  no   5   6
  yes  1   4
```

The table function automatically removes the NA rows from the calculation.